# When to use Data(contentsOf:) vs Session.dataTask(with:completionHandler:)?

Tags: ios, swift, download, uiimage

I have a scenario where I want to download some image from the internet, based on a URL, and just return a UIImage or nil (if not possible).
Looking for options of how to do this, I basically found two options:

1. using `Data(contentsOf:)` on a global thread, for example, to not freeze UI
2. using `session.dataTask(with:completionHandler:)`

It seems the second approach is recommended, but I wanted to know more the pros and cons of each one and why the second one (if I'm correct) is the best options. Or, if there is a better solution.

Comment: `Data(contentsOf:)` is great for one-off scripts, where you would be waiting on a result without an interactive UI. I don't know of much of a use for it beyond that, though.

Comment: You should never use `Data(contentsOf:)` for non local resources. From the docs **Important
Don't use this synchronous initializer to request network-based URLs. For network-based URLs, this method can block the current thread for tens of seconds on a slow network, resulting in a poor user experience, and in iOS, may cause your app to be terminated.
Instead, for non-file URLs, consider using the dataTask(with:completionHandler:) method of the URLSession class. See Fetching Website Data into Memory for an example.** https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1413892-init

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/fetching_website_data_into_memory